# How can I use STM32 sleep mode with UART

Tags: stm32, uart, sleep-mode, mcu

I want to use sleep mode because of the power consumption of the MCU. My aim is basic, but I can not use the process.

I will get data from another MCU via UART. If one of my data is 6, I want to wake-up my MCU and I want to keep it awake. If it is not 6, I want to keep it in sleep mode.

There are two options for me, the first one as I mentioned earlier is UART data, the second one is my ZeroCross interrupt. But both aim is for me. I do not understand how to use it with basic if else conditions.

```
if (rxdata==6){
//wake-up
}

else if (!rxdata==6){
//sleep-mode
}
```

Comment: If you configured you r mcu to enter sleep mode and wake up upon data rx then the mcu will stay awake whatever data you receive. You want to check for `rxdata != 6` to tell whether you want it to sleep again.

Comment: Thank you. I editted as you recommend. Can you help me the code side. There is some functions but ı could not understand these barely

Comment: First things first, enter the proper deep sleep mode (see the HAL examples), then configure and play with uart, finally enable wake up of the MCU to enter deep sleep and wake upon uart .. you can post pieces of code which cause you trouble (which configurations, which functions, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand how to use it with basic if else conditions.

You can't as if you sleep, the core will not be executing any code.

If your UART can detect a particular character, it can invoke the interrupt which will wake the core.